# Is the EDL v1.0 GPL-compatible?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility

The [GPL compatiblity overview compiled by the GNU foundation](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html) does not mention the [Eclipse Distribution License](https://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php).

Is this license compatible with the AGPL v3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Eclipse Distribution License (EDL) is just an alternative name for the BSD 3-clause license, listed by the GNU project as the [modified BSD license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#ModifiedBSD).

This is a highly permissive license that is widely compatible with other licenses, including the GPL and AGPL in all versions.